# Finding relative image offsets for image stitching with stitching class in openCV, python

Tags: python, opencv, image-stitching

Using the Stitching class in python, I'd like to discover the offsets used after successfully stitching.
For example:

```
import cv2
img1=cv2.imread(<some image>)
img2=cv2.imread(<some other image>)
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(cv2.Stitcher_SCANS)        
status, pano = stitcher.stitch(img1,img2])
```

assuming success (status = 0), the stitched result is stored in pano. Unless they are the same image, img1] and img2 are stitched with some translation (incl. shifting, warping, etc). How can I obtain information about the translations?

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html#details) for stick in `C++` doesn't show any function to get these information. Probably version for `Python` will also not give these information. Maybe you would have to check in source code how it use it and if it keeps somewhere these information.

Comment: Thanks furas, I saw there was no documentation on it, but I was hoping I was wrong. I'll use different libraries.

Comment: Maybe have a look on the [stitching](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/stitching) library (Disclaimer: I'm the author)